# Best method to move "C:\Users" on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, file-transfer

I am currently working on relocate my `C:\Users-Folder`. I found some solutions on the internet, but none of them are working for me.

I already tried:

- Log in with Administrator Account, move Folder and Symlink to other HDD
- Edit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList-Values`
- Audit-Mode with Sysprep.exe

I got issues like not working metro apps, not working store-purchases even not working desktop applications (Adobe Creative Suite, Steam,...)

It would be great if you have a solution, to move the `C:\Users-Folder`, which is working well on Windows 8.

Comment: it can be done in audit mode during or after installation of W8...http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4275-user-profiles-relocate-another-partition-disk.html

Comment: @Moab: Should be an Answer.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I already tried this, with audit mode. The problem is that you get a Profile named "Username.Computername" and Adobe Creative Suite doesn't support Accounts with "."

Comment: You can fix that "." problem with `MKLINK /J`. It takes all of the time to type the command and hit `Enter`.

Comment: Moving Users is not recommended by Microsoft and can cause issues with Updates http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949977

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLVED!
I just used mklink /J to link C:\Users to (in my case) E:\Users and it worked very well.

```
D:> mklink /J Users E:\Users
Junction created for Users <<===>> D:\Users
```

I just was a bit confused about the folders, because in Windows Explorer there are still at C:\ but when you install Programs or copy Files to the Directory the storage on (in my case) E:\Users will be used.

You can check the Junction-Point in CMD by typing "dir" in your Systemdrive, you will see the junction-point and the storage-path.

Thank you

Comment: Did this work as the full solution, or did you have to use the Audit Mode or similar approach first and then do this to complete the transition? Also, did you have to copy existing folders over to the new location and if so, how did you do this?