# Disk Partitioning and moving the user directory to the partioned drive in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, user-profiles

I have recently purchased a Dell Inspiron Laptop with1.9 Ghz  Intel 2127U Processor, 4GB DDR3L RAM, 500 GB SATA HDD and Windows 8 (64 bit) pre-installed Operating system.

Now is it really beneficial to partition the C: Drive and move the USER directory to the partitioned drive.

If so then, how do I go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Use Windows-X key combination.
2. Choose an option "Disk Management".
3. Click on the "C:" drive under the "Volume" category to select it.
4. Click on the "Action" menu, select "All tasks," and then click on "Shrink Volume."
5. Enter the amount of drive space you wish to remove from the "C:" drive. You can also use the arrows to select that amount. Then click on "Shrink." In the next step, you will use this space to create the new partition. If you use it all your C:\ will have no space left.
6. Right-click on the grey box with the "Unallocated" label and choose the "New Simple Volume" option. This unallocated space is the space you have removed from drive "C:." You will now have to turn it into a new partition which your computer can use to store data.
7. Click on "Next," once the "New Simple Volume" wizard has opened. Choose the amount of drive space, the drive letter and the name of the partition. Then click on "Finish." Your computer will now format that space and create your new partition. You will be able to see that new partition, along with its new drive letter, in the "My Computer" folder of Windows Explorer.
8. You can then move the folders by following [best Method to move "C:\Users" on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/479142/best-method-to-move-c-users-on-windows-8)

Comment: I am sorry but did not quite understand point no.8. (I have visited the link and it does not give any detailed instructions). Would be great if you can elaborate further. Also I read some comments that updates will get affected and apps from windows store will not download properly if we move he user directory away from system drive. Kindly clarify.

Comment: when you have created you need partition it will show up in disk management as a grey box with "Unallocated". You need to create a drive  by following step 6.